# Implement logic to show only one button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I'm trying to implement a JSTL logic which displayed submit buttons based on the following logic:

```
<c:choose>
            <!--  if it's demo mode skip every limit check, if not check them -->
            <c:when test="#{dashboard.demoMode == 'false'}">
                    <c:when test="#{dashboard.allowedTrades == 0}">
                           <h:commandButton id="buyx" x:data-toggle="modal" x:data-target="#hitsModal" />    
                    </c:when>

                    <c:when test="#{dashboard.currentBalance == 0}">
                           <h:commandButton id="buyz" x:data-toggle="modal" x:data-target="#chargeModal" />
                    </c:when>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                   <h:commandButton id="buy" action="#{dashboard.calculateProcessing}" />
            </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

But unfortunately I get 2 buttons - `buyx` `buyz`. These buttons are displayed together. Only one button should be displayed.

Is there some way to implement the code in a way to display just one button at a time?

Comment: The inner `c:when` tag should also has its own container `c:choose` tag.

Comment: @TheBitman: Like in my answer... You are allowed to upvote it...The original poster will take the answer and we'll most likely not hear from him again (he has been online 17 minutes ago without providing any feedback)

Comment: @Kukeltje This time just for you because you gave me a answer: I'm not answering because I'm at work. I will test it later at home.

Comment: But even this feedback is appreciated... Always... So we know action is (going to be) taken... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to implement the code in a way to display just one button at a time?

Yes there is, by not using the jstl `c:when` in a weird nested way but wrapping the inner ones in a `c:choose` or changing them to `c:if`'s.

Off-topic the commandButtons in them look weird.